# Why the word "baba" was used for Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, name

I have listened from many peoples, they are calling Lord Shiva as baba, baba vishwanath etc. Does this word have an Urdu origin? Is there was a specific reason behind calling him baba & when it was started?

Comment: The question "Does this word have an Urdu origin?" is more suited to linguistics stack exchange. We can't trace the exact time when devotees started to call Lord Shiva as baba, but certainly since we won't find the word in scriptures, we can say that this practice is fairly modern. The word doesn't sound like a Urdu word and mostly used to mention the highest position in local speech .

Comment: Baba is not even a word of Sanskrit or Hindi. Its derived from the word "Babul/Kabul" which means "Father" came in Hindi from Semite-Arabic languages during Mughal invasion.  Father in Sanskrit is Pitra/Pitah which is derived from Utpati(creator).

Comment: BaBa in reality means "nonsense talk/Babble" like of a child, as its derived from the word https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Babel of Babylon. Later it was adopted by greeks and in its words like "Biblion" which meant book and which later became root of words like "Bible", "Bibliography", "Baby", "Babble" etc. in PIE languages of today. The word "Biblion/Babylon/Babble" that originally meant nonsense talk is used to represent knowledge/book today by Europeans and in their languages.

Comment: Baba has become Papa among so called brainwashed modern Hindus who want to mindlessly ape lawless European culture. Christians call it Pope, the Father of Vatican. When in original Sanskrit-Hindi, Paap(Papa-Pope-Pop) means sins and paapi is sinner.