# is the term baba mentioned in scriptures?

Tags: terminology, saint

we the have titles called BABA for saints like

Neem karoli Baba

Sai Baba

Satya Sai Baba

Baba Ramdev

Is scriptures talks about this baba term and what does it mean? Could any saint be given baba titles?

Comment: Baba is not Sanskrit word. So, it is not mentioned.

Comment: There's already similar question asked.  [Why the word "baba" was used for Lord Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37160/3500)